# DCMTK integration with android project

Tags: android, dicom, dcmtk

I want to use DCMTK to view and read DICOM files.I installed the NDK required for it.But I dont know how DCMTK works.Anybody has any idea how it works??Please guide.

Comment: Have you checked the official documentation? http://support.dcmtk.org/docs/index.html

Answer (score 4):

Android support has just been added to the DCMTK as the following [commit](http://git.dcmtk.org/web?p=dcmtk.git;a=commit;h=ebe8769644dccfccc076ed90e11789a1f18a79ba) shows. Detailed build instructions will follow in a couple of days.

Comment: Here is the link to the build instructions: http://support.dcmtk.org/redmine/projects/dcmtk/wiki/Howto_CompileAndroid